# How do I express static code in XAML?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a control that I would like to be static, but instead of writing it in code, i would like it to be in the XAML, so that I can still design edit and play around with it in Blend.

Basically, within my class, I have the code:

```
public static TextBox s_notepad = new TextBox();
```

*I've altered my code to attempt to make it easier to explain.*

If anyone knows the equivalent to this in XAML, it would be fantastic if they could let me know.

Thanks,

Lloyd

Comment: Are you trying to make a single XAML object globally accessible? If not, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Yeh more or less, there's going to be one instance of it for the full application.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. WPF objects can only have one logical parent. I think what you want is a global style that affects all instances of a type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAML code works by instance you cannot declare static code into your XAML.

But you can use the x:Static keywords in order to have access to static property from other objects.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it would be `<TextBox/>` in XAML. Almost all of the objects have a direct mapping to XAML and can be found directly in the Help files under the XAML section on the page if there is a way of expressing it in XAML.

Comment: He's not asking how to put a simple TextBox on the screen... but rather if there is a way to make it *static*, instead of an *instance variable*

Comment: Yeah, I jumped the gun here without reading. Sorry about that. The downvote is well-deserved.